# Link_to :Action won't call Controller Method -- Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, routes, link-to

I'm trying to figure out why my link_to isn't working how I thought it would. In my application, I have a database of prizes. When a user clicks on the link_to, the controller should access the selected action (in this case, "result1") and perform the action's method on the resultpage view. From testing, it appears as if the link_to is completely ignoring the :action => 'result1' and just defaults to doing the Show method.

Any idea why the link_to is completely ignoring the **:action => 'result1'**?

**First View:** views/start/start.html.erb view:

```
<%=link_to 'result', resultpage_path, :controller => 'resultpage', :action => 'result1', :class => 'btn btn-default'%>
```

**Resultpage Controller:** controllers/resultpage_controller.rb

```
class ResultpageController < ApplicationController

def index
end

# regardless of what is in the :action =>, the controller always calls Show.
def show
  @prize = Prize.first
  render :index
end

# if i make the :action => 'result1', the controller still calls Show.
def result1
  @prize = Prize.last
  render :index
end
```

**Results View:** resultspage/index.html.erb

```
  <h2><%= @prize.title %></h2>
  <p><%= @prize.description %></p>
```

**Routes:**

```
resources :resultpage do
    get 'index'
    get 'show'
end

resources :prizes
```

Answer (score 0):

Make routes with such content

```
resources :resulpages do
  get :result1
end
```

Use such link

```
= link_to 'result', result1_resultpage_paths
```

And modify tour controller

```
class ResultpageController < ApplicationController
```

And, BTW read this article carefully